# How to add location for users and events

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables `users and events`, i want assign location to my users (`address, country, city`...) and also my events need to be located with address country and city.

Should i create a separate table called `location` with two foreign keys `user_id` and `event_id` then add relation `user has_one location`, `event has_one location` or just add these column (address, country, city) in each table (users and events)

I ask this question because if i create a separate table location it will be like a join table between users and events : `location belongs_to user and location belongs_to event`,
but in reality there is no relation between users and events through location, so i think i'm confusing things, any explication will be helpful, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a separate table `location` instead of storing address information in `users` and `events` tables, and I think a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) is what sounds like a good association for your case.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, as: :locatable
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, as: :locatable
end
```

And your migration for `location` would be:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.integer :locatable_id
      t.string  :locatable_type
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: oh yes i'm stupid, you are right, thank you i forgot polymorphic assocation :)

Answer (score 1):

The general Rails paradigm of keeping things DRY is best served by decoupling resources from one another. While both approaches you've depicted are possible, the *Rails way* of accomplishing this would be to create a separate `Location` model and create associations between the two existing models from there.

```
# app/models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord
    has_many :users
    has_many :events

    attr_accessible :address, :country, :city
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord
    belongs_to :location # Foreign key is location is on the User model
end

# app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord
    belongs_to :location # Foreign key to location is on the Event model
end
```

Comment: do you want say has_many :events in the location model line 2

Comment: also in event model you should correct blogs_to location :) but this is not possible because i have also address in location, so  location can't has many users, the same thing for events, because each time user want to create a new event he should fill location info

Comment: you are right ,it's possible if some people live in the same house address, but i think @vinodadhikary solution is what i search :)